# I am having problem understanding the use of asterisk in C

Tags: c, pointers

Sometimes it is used in this way like `int * ptr` which i know means that we are creating a pointer but in some other cases it is used in this way `int *ptr` and also in this way `int* ptr`.

Can you plz explain me what's happening in the last two ways.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuqYW.png)

Comment: They're the same thing; defining `x` as a variable that's a pointer to int.

Comment: It is the same. Both expressions create a pointer, you have to take into account that spaces are ignore by `C` compiler.

Comment: they are all same

Comment: @Shawn you mean both of them are used as a dereference.

Comment: No, no dereferencing. They're just variable definitions.

Comment: C ignores the spaces in those examples.  So `int *x`, `int* x`, and `int*x` are all equivalent.  The most logical way to group it matches grouping of the syntax, i.e. `int *x`.  Some beginners like `int* x`, but they're missing the fact that `int* x, y` only makes `x` a pointer, while `y` is an `int`.  That's why `int *x, y` makes more sense.